# Why does selling covered calls result in a negative balance in my account?

Tags: options, schwab

When I sell covered calls I see the balance that I was paid (the premium) represented as a negative number under the "options" section of my balances.  Why?  It makes sense to me that the premium would be assumed mine (not a debit or something I'm waiting on).

Comment: Probably a question for your broker. I see a negative only when the cost of my short call has gone up since I sold it (because closing it will result in a loss).

Comment: @HartCO Schwab as in the tags

Comment: @Hart Co -If you own a security, it has a positive value which you realize when you sell the security.  If you are short a security, it has a negative value which is eliminated when you buy the security to close.   In an account page, There are 3 components:  Market Price, Market Value of Position and P&L.  If the price of a short call goes up, the call incurs a loss.  That's P&L.  However, the short call is a liability and that liability also becomes more negative as the call's price goes up (Market Value).

Answer (score 3):

You are short the call.  It is a liability that you must satisfy and therefore the Market Value is negative.

Here's an example that might be an easier way to understand it.  You sell a call for $10.  Assuming no commissions and fees, $1,000 is deposited into your account.  Your cash balance increases by $1,000.  Has you account value gone up by $1,000?  No, because if the call's price is still $10, it's a $1,000 liability.  That is how much it would cost for you to buy it back.   Plus $1,000 and minus $1,000 equals zero and therefore your account value is unchanged.

Comment: I own the stock though (the call is covered), and the premium is immediately mine, right?

Comment: @HH- Apologize to Carole Baskin - Yes, the premium is yours, no matter what.  Ignoring upside opportunity cost, your risk is if the stock's price drops more than the amount of the premium received.

Comment: Bob - yeah that's how I understand it as well (but I don't mind if the stock drops, since I'm ok with holding it long term).  It's just the negative balance on the broker's site that confuses me

Comment: I bought the call Bob mentioned. I am long one contract, currently worth $1000. How would you think your acct would reflect your position? You are short that call, and since its value is $1000, it's -$1000 on your side.